# Retrieve only some fields from sub-document based on value from main document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in my mongodb which is as follows

```
{
_id: ObjectId("5fa917baffdd553806e96ca4"),
priority: 1,
fields: {
    1: {
        id: NumberInt("1"),
        value: NumberInt("1"),
        label: "Din 1",
        dimension: null,
        valueHuman: "1"
    },
    9: {
        id: NumberInt("9"),
        value: NumberInt("259"),
        label: "",
        dimension: "",
        valueHuman: ""
    }
   }
  }
```

what i want to do is to fetch fields based on the value of priority
such as i should get

```
{
_id: ObjectId("5fa917baffdd553806e96ca4"),
priority: 1,
fields: {
    1: {
        id: NumberInt("1"),
        value: NumberInt("1"),
        label: "Din 1",
        dimension: null,
        valueHuman: "1"
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$objectToArray` convert `fields` object to array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of above converted fields array and check condition if field match, `$toInt` to convert string number to integer
- `$arrayToObject` back to convert array to object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      fields: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $filter: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$fields" },
            cond: {
              $eq: [{ $toInt: "$$this.k" }, "$priority"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T47XleN--Uh)

Comment: sir what does $$this.k does

Comment: $objectToArray will convert your object to k(key) and v(value) format, like `[{ k: "1", v: "ABC" ... }]` and $$this indicates current instance of $filter / or temporary variable, if you want to access k, and v fields then you need to use $$this.

Comment: what if i want to concat somevalue with $$this cuz in my realdatabase the column of subdocuments of fields is io1 etc

Comment: not getting you exactly can you provide actual and expected document.

Comment: sir check my edieted question i dont have string against column but an object

Comment: which field you want in result? name or post? or full object?

Comment: sir check my question this is my real collection and after running your query i am getting 0 fields